Odoo api connection in php / xmlrpc
I'm trying to connect to Odoo API in php to sync stock with my e-commerce, but I can't figure out why my connexion is not working.
I've double check my Odoo credentials, my ripcord folder path is the right one and in 755 chmod, I also have an .htaccess for xmlrpc with the following :
Order deny,allow 
Allow from all 

My file look like this (as specified in Odoo doc https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/external_api.html)
require_once('ripcord/ripcord.php');
$url = 'https://my-db.odoo.com';
$db = 'my-db';
$username = 'email@domain.be'; 
$password = 'my-password';

$common = ripcord::client("$url/xmlrpc/2/common");
$uid = $common->authenticate($db, $username, $password, array());

if(!empty($uid)){
    echo "Successfully sign in with the user id of : " . $uid . '';
}else{
    echo "Failed to sign in";
}

I can't figure out where the problem is.
I don't have that much knowledge on server management, but from what I found online I don't need something special except this ripcord.
Someone have any idea ?
